# fetch django model string fields as str instead of unicode

Tags: python, django, string, unicode

django fetches `CharField` fields as `unicode`, whereas sometimes `str` is required. It is inefficient and tedious to write code that loops over the fields, checks the type and if it is `unicode` casts it to `str`.

Is there already a feature that can handle it?
If not what would be the most elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Can you explain why it matters? What's wrong with unicode strings? Sometimes str is required by what?

Comment: @TomRose - maybe somewhere I checked `type(some_var) is str` which failed for unicode, maybe some 3rd party low level implementation package had trouble with unicode...

Comment: use `isinstance(some_var,basestring)` to check for all types of strings

Comment: @TomRose - If I recall correctly, [quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) with python bindings does not handle unicode well

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the models.CharField class and override the to_python method:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from django.db.models import CharField

class ByteStringField(CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str) or value is None:
            return value
        return smart_str(value)
```

smart_str is the equivalent for bytestrings of the smart_unicode function normally used in CharFields.

EDIT: As Jonathan says, if you're using South, remember to [extend south's introspection rules](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html#extending-introspection).

Comment: that would require [extending south's introspection](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html#extending-introspection), right?